# C++11 lazy worker thread initialization and idle termination

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

The goal is to have a lazily spawned worker thread that then terminates itself after being idle for a set amount of time. My intention is to use a similar technique in some networking code where having large number of idle threads is considered undesirable. Below is an example singleton class that I hope does the job. Multithreading is hardly my strong point and I'd appreciate a second set of eyes to make sure I haven't overlooked something obvious.

Thanking you guys in anticipation!

```
class lazyWorkerIdleTerminate {
    typedef enum state {
        STARTED,
        STOPPING,
        STOPPED
    } state_t;

    std::queue<std::string> queue;
    std::mutex              mutex;
    std::thread             thread;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::atomic<state_t>    state = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(STOPPED);

    void process() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex, std::defer_lock);

        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            while (queue.empty()) {
                if (condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(30)) == std::cv_status::timeout || state == STOPPING) {
                    state = STOPPED;
                    return;
                }
            }
            std::string work = queue.front();
            queue.pop();
            lock.unlock();

            // Some processing here...
        }
    }

public:
    static lazyWorkerIdleTerminate& instance() {
        static lazyWorkerIdleTerminate instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void doWork(std::string work) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            queue.push(work);
            if (state == STOPPED) {
                state = STARTED;
                if (thread.joinable()) thread.detach();
                thread = std::thread(&lazyWorkerIdleTerminate::process, this);
                return;
            }
        }
        condition.notify_one();
    }

    void stop() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            if (state != STARTED) return;
            state = STOPPING;
        }
        condition.notify_one();
        thread.join();
    }

    lazyWorkerIdleTerminate() {}

    ~lazyWorkerIdleTerminate() {
        stop();
    }
};
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for working code

Comment: I question your motivation. While a thread is blocked on a condition variable it takes almost no resources or CPU time. spooling up and destroying idle threads seems to me to be less efficient that just leaving the thread idle.

Comment: @BryanChen thanks didn't know such an oasis existed!

Comment: @RichardHodges Point taken. Maybe it would help if I expanded a little more: each worker thread is going to be responsible for maintaining a secure connection with a server. So it's not so much a performance issue as it is a number of connections one.

Comment: An approach I might start with would be to maintain a `boost::asio::io_service` for each worker. Requests can be fed to each service loop via `io_service::post()`. Each io_service loop can get deadline timers on itself. You'll have a fully reactive subsystem in which each worker thread drops out of its run loop and ends when there is no more work to do (i.e. connection closed).

Comment: `typedef enum`? What language is this?!

Comment: @KerrekSB C++ :) In this case it serves no purpose! But in general I like having 'X' and 'X_t' aliases for my enum. I can declare the enum as 'X_t'. It then makes it a little nicer when referencing the enum outside of its scope to say 'X:Y' rather than 'X_t:Y'.

Comment: @amarcus: Since your enum isn't scoped, just `Y` would work, too.

Comment: @KerrekSB correct, it's useless here. Bad habit!